# Header/Content alignment/positioning

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a website with a header that is fixed at top but always centered (unless the screen is too small I want it to sit on the left side and crop at the right), and then I want my content to scroll up underneath the header so that the header stays as is, but you can scroll through the bottom of the page. Here is the code I have now:

```
<body>
<div id="header_img">
<span class="class1">
<a href="index.html"><h2>HEATHER</h2></a></span>
<p class="style5">
419.953.5098<br>
<span class="class2">
<a href ="mailto:obringhm@mail.uc.edu">obringhm@mail.uc.edu</a></span></p>

<table>
<tr>
<td><a href="b5_photo_portrait.html">portraits</a></td>
<td><a href="b5_photo_object.html">objects</a></td>
<td>records
</td>
</tr>
</table>  
</div>

<div id="header_img2" style="scroll:auto">
<img class="project14"src="images/image17.jpg">
<img class="project15" src="images/image16.jpg">
<img class="project16" src="images/image20.jpg">
<h3>Portrait Series</h3>
<p>This project is an exploration of composition within a photograph and
the studying of correct value tones in a picture.
<br><br>
Completed: December 2011<br>
Tools: Film Photography
<br></p>
</div>
</body>
```

and the css:

```
#header_img {
 height: 180px;
 background: #E2E2E2;
 width: 998px;
 position: fixed;
 top: -25px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 z-index: 11;
 box-shadow: 0 6px 10px -10px #888;
 } 
 #header_img2 {
 height: 800px;
 background: E2E2E2; 
 width: 998px;
 position: relative;
 top: 200;
 z-index: 10;
 }
```

Right now, I have the content scrolling underneath the header, but the header is fixed to the left!

Comment: How about creating a jsfiddle so we can play around with it?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly your code is a bit of a mess. Your problem is arising because your div is inside a container with no width set. Setting a width and margin on the body or putting your code inside a container with a width and margin will fix your issue.

```
body{width:960px; margin:0 auto;}
```

Now the other issues.

1. I have no idea why you have top set to a negative value on the first div but it's knocking your content off the top of the page.
2. Your top setting on the second div is 200 which won't work it has to have the px so 200px.
3. Box shadows only have 4 settings you have 5.
4. You're using tables where you shouldn't be using tables.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/r43me/2/